# Querying an extents directly

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Is it possible to query database extents directly without specifying name of a table ?

For example when I fire the command `.show database extents` , I get a list of extents in the given database. If I pick a specific extent id from the result , or in general any extent id belonging to that database , is there a way to query it without reference to table name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **not** recommended to take any kind of dependency on an extent ID.

Though your use case isn't clear nor standard, it is possible to run a query as follows:

```
union * 
| where extent_id() == '6810147e-1234-1234-1234-d3649e3d3a83'
| take 10
```

Comment: Append `| project Packed = pack_all(true) | evaluate bag_unpack(Packed)` to get only columns from the source table without needing to know in advance what they are.